Is it possible to prove that any two points of a convex complete metric space are connected by some metric segment without the axiom of choice?
We say that a point $m$ is between points $p$ and $q$ of a metric space $(M, d)$ if $d(p, q) = d(p, m) + d(m, q)$ and $p ≠ m ≠ q$.
A metric space $M$ is said to be metrically convex if given any two points $p, q ∈ M$ there exists at least one point $m ∈ M$ such that $m$ is between $p$ and $q$.
A subset $S$ of a metric space $M$ is called a metric segment with endpoints $p, q ∈ S$ if there exists a closed interval $[a, b]$ in the real line $ \mathbb R $ and an isometry $φ$ which maps $[a, b]$ onto $S$ with $φ(a) = p$ and $φ(b) = q$.
If $M$ is a complete and convex metric space, then each two points of $M$ are the endpoints of some metric segment of $M$. Can the previous statement be proved using some weaker axiom than the axiom of choice (AC) (the axiom of dependent choice (DC), for example)?
(The statement in my question is easy to prove using Zorn's lemma, but in the case of a compact metric space, DC suffices in the proof.)

One thing to consider is that without countable choice, there's at least two inequivalent definitions of 'complete metric space.'

@JamesEHanson A metric space M is called complete if every Cauchy sequence of points in M has a limit. This is the definition of completeness that I use.

New related question. Is the statement that every convex complete metric space has midpoints equivalent to the axiom of dependent choice (DC)? If anyone knows and wants to answer, (s)he can answer here.

If dependent choice fails then there is a convex complete metric space metric space with two points not connected by a segment. I'm not yet sure about the converse. It seems clear that $\mathsf{DC}_{\omega_1}$ is sufficient to show that arbitrary convex complete metric spaces have segments, so the precise amount of choice needed is something greater than $\mathsf{DC}$ but at most $\mathsf{DC}_{\omega_1}$.

Assume dependent choice is false and let $(T,\sqsubseteq)$ be a tree (i.e., a partial order with the property that for any $a$, $\{b \in T : b \sqsubseteq a\}$ is well-ordered) with no maximal elements and no infinite paths. Let $x_0$ be the unique minimal element of $T$.
Let $T^\ast = \{x_0\} \cup ((T \setminus \{x_0\}) \times (0,1])$. We will define a metric on $T^\ast \cup \{x_1\}$, where $x_1$ is some new element. Define a partial order $\leq$ on $T^\ast$ as follows: $x_0$ is the unique minimal element. For any $(a,r)$ and $(b,s)$, $(a,r) \leq (b,s)$ if and only if either $a\sqsubset b$ or $a=b$ and $r \leq s$. (Basically we've taken the tree $T$ and filled in each line segment between nodes with actual points and extended the partial order in the obvious way.)
It's relatively straightforward to check that under $\leq$, any two elements of $T^\ast$ have a meet (i.e., a greatest lower bound). Let $a \wedge b$ be the meet of any $a$ and $b$ in $T^\ast$.
Now define a height function $h$ on $T^\ast$ as follows: $h(x_0) = 0$. For any $a \in T$ and $r \in (0,1]$,
$$ h((a,r)) = \frac{1}{2} - 2^{-|\{b \in T : b \sqsubset a\}|-1}(2-r).$$
So, for example, if $a$ is a direct child of $x_0$, then $h((a,r)) = \frac{1}{2} - 2^{-1-1}(2-r)= \frac{r}{4}$. If $a \in T$ is an element of height $2$ (i.e., a child of a child of $x_0)$, then $h((a,r)) = \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{r}{8}$. For height $3$, we get $h((a,r)) = \frac{3}{8} + \frac{r}{16}$. Note that the supremum of the values of $h$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.
Now use $h$ to define a metric on $T^\ast \cup \{x_1\}$. For any $y,z \in T^\ast$, we let $d(y,z) = h(y) + h(z) - 2h(y\wedge z)$. It's a little tedious but not hard to show that this satisfies the triangle inequality. For any $y \in T^\ast$, we let $d(y,x_1) = 1-h(y)$. To see that this satisfies the triangle inequality, note that for any $y,z \in T^\ast$, we have that $d(y,z) \leq 1$ but $d(y,x_1) + d(x_1,z) \geq 1$.
Call this metric space $(X,d)$. Note that we clearly do not have a segment between $x_0$ and $x_1$ because no other points are less than distance $\frac{1}{2}$ from $x_1$.
I claim that $(X,d)$ is convex and complete (both in the Cauchy sequence sense and in the Cauchy filter sense). Convexity is relatively straightforward. ($(T^\ast,d)$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-tree, which is always convex. Convexity between $x_1$ and points in $T^\ast$ can be checked directly.) Completeness follows from the fact that for any Cauchy sequence $(y_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ of elements of $T^\ast$, we must have that there is an $r < \frac{1}{2}$ such that $h(y_i) < r$ for all $i$.
For Cauchy filter completeness one shows that there's a way of converting any given Cauchy filter to a Cauchy sequence converging to the same point. Alternatively one could observe that if a Cauchy filter in $T^\ast$ has unbounded $h$-value, then its limit point would yield a path through $T$.

Remarkable.  Could you comment on why Shoenfield absoluteness would not apply here?

@MikhailKatz The metric spaces here aren't separable. Note that for countable trees, dependent choice is provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$. For a separable metric space you could apply Shoenfield absoluteness, but there's probably also a more direct proof.

You may want to mention the issue of separability somewhere :-)

@JamesEHanson Interesting construction. Assuming ¬DC, you constructed a bizarre tree with no maximal elements and no branches, and then switched from it to an R-tree. And you extended this R-tree to a convex complete metric space with a gap. So the statement in my question implies DC. I suspect the converse is also true. If it were true, then DC and the statement in my question would be equivalent. (Baire's category theorem for complete metric spaces is equivalent to DC, for example.)

@JamesEHanson And yes, $\mathsf{DC}{\omega_1}$ implies the statement in my question. I've done the proof. Assuming $\mathsf{DC}{\omega_1}$, I constructed an increasing $ \omega_1 $ sequence of subspaces isometric with subspaces in $ \mathbb R $, with each space of larger index encroaching on the gaps in spaces of smaller index. In the proof of the convexity of the sum of these subspaces, I then used the fact that a monotone $ \omega_1 $ sequence of real numbers is constant from a certain index ...

@JamesEHanson Thank you for your answer.
